# Ext js6.2, Navigate Textfields using Arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm using Ext Js v6.2 Grid, In my application, I have three Group of textfield, **I've like to Navigate Textfield using ArrowKey's [UP][DOWN][RIGHT][LEFT]** Below code not firing in Ext js, please solve the problem.

**Script**

```
$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
            $(".move:focus").next().focus();
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
            $(".move:focus").prev().focus();
        }
    }
);
```

[LIKE THIS-I WANT-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ4PJ/)

​

Comment: Please provide Extjs code also for better answer. Create a sencha fiddle link: http://www.jsonwrapper.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=tags&utm_campaign=queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`KeyNav`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.util.KeyNav.html) in ExtJS.

`Ext.util.KeyNav` provides a convenient wrapper for normalized keyboard navigation. KeyNav allows you to bind navigation keys to function calls that will get called when the keys are pressed, providing an easy way to implement custom navigation schemes for any UI component.

In ExtJs have method [`next()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-next) and [`prev()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-prev) so you can use for your component like this `textfield.next()` and  `textfield.prev()`.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2adu)**, I have created a demo using `Ext.util.KeyNav` and it is working as per your requirement. Hope this will help you or guide you to achieve your requirement.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: ' Example with key Navigation',
    layout: 'hbox',
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        flex: 1,
        margin: 10
    },
    items: [{
        emptyText: 'A'
    }, {
        emptyText: 'B'
    }, {
        emptyText: 'C'
    }, {
        emptyText: 'D'
    }, {
        emptyText: 'E'
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            var panel = this;
            panel.keynav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', {
                target: Ext.getBody(),
                scope: panel,
                left: panel.doFocusToText,
                right: panel.doFocusToText
            });
        }
    },
    /*
    * this will fire on left or right key pressed.
    * @param {Event} e
    */
    doFocusToText: function (e) { //{ http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.EventObject }
        var panel = this,
            current = panel.down('[hasFocus=true]');

        if (e.LEFT == e.getKey()) {
            if (current.prev()) {
                current.prev().focus();
            }
        } else {
            if (current.next()) {
                current.next().focus();
            }
        }
    }
});
```